# How to randomly select an enum in Swift

Tags: swift, random, enums

```
enum randomName: UInt32 {
        case name1
        case name2
        case name3
        case name4
        case name5
        case name6
        case name7
        case name8
    }
```

I want to make a function to randomly pick a name from the enum. How do I do that?

Comment: Code so far? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: is Swift convention to name your enumeration starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Oh cool. Good to know. thx

Comment: It's still 2.2 I am running. But that just reminded me to update to 3.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
randomName(rawValue: arc4random_uniform(randomName.name8.rawValue + 1))
```